# Syntax for accessing objects

Tags: php, codeigniter

So I'm working with CodeIgniter and I want to access the result object of my database query.

I know how to access a certain entry via result_array

```
$foo = $result->result_array();
$bar = $foo[8]['firstname'];

echo $bar;
```

What I don't know is how to access it via

```
$foo = $result->result_object();
$bar = …
```

I would appreciate a little help and especially a link to a tutorial on how to do this. This may seem lazy, but as you can see from the title of this question, I just don't know what to search for.

Comment: You would use it just like you used the `$result` object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to use

```
$foo = $result->result();
$bar = $foo[8]->firstname;

echo $bar;
```

Comment: And i thought I tried all possible variations of brackets and arrows.. thank you!

Comment: this will select array foo's 8th object's firstname

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
if($result -> num_rows() > 0)
    {
        return $result -> result();
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
```

Now you can loop your results:

```
foreach($result as $key => $value)
    {
        print $result[$key] -> attrib;
    }
```

Or this:

```
if($result -> num_rows() == 1)
    {
        foreach($result -> result() as $row)
        {
            return $row;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
```

Now can access your object:

```
print $result -> attrib;
```

Also, look here: [Tutorial](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/results.html)